# Affect Input CSS Using Javascript and a Select with Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement the following: change the CSS property `visibility:` of an`<input>` tag using a javascript function when the user selects an `<option>` from a `<select>`.

Here's my code so far:

main.js:

```
function change_css(){
    if( $('#billing_method').val() == "CLICK THIS TO CHANGE VISIBILITY" ){
        $('#the_input').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' });
    }else{
        $('#the_input').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden' });
    }
}
```

page.html:

```
<select name="billing_method">
    <option onClick='change_css()'>-- SELECT AN OPTION --></option>
    <option onClick='change_css()'>CLICK THIS TO CHANGE VISIBILITY</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="the_input" value="" placeholder="I AM THE INPUT" />
```

styles.css:

```
#the_input{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnDwr/3/)

Comment: change select name attribute to id

Comment: sorry, is included now

Comment: @MaVRoSCy no change in outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues

- Your select has a name not an id so you aren't selecting it
- Use the change event on the select to call your function. Avoid using click events on option especially if what you want to do is check if the selection changed.

.

```
<select onchange='change_css()' name="billing_method" id="billing_method">
    <option>-- SELECT AN OPTION --></option>
    <optio>CLICK THIS TO CHANGE VISIBILITY</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rnDwr/5/

Answer (score 2):

Option does not respond to `onClick`.  You have to use the `change` event from `select`

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "CLICK THIS TO CHANGE VISIBILITY" ){
        $('#the_input').css({ 'visibility': 'visible' });
    }else{
        $('#the_input').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden' });
    }
});
```

and remove the on click

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself some jQuery and write it in plain JavaScript:

```
var select = document.querySelector('select[name=billing_method]');
var input = document.querySelector('#the_input');
var changeCSS = function () {
    var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    if (val.toLowerCase() === 'click this to change visibility') {
        input.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        input.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
};
select.onchange = changeCSS;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/UNL4k

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using jQuery, this could be much simplier:

```
$('#billing_method').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val('CLICK THIS TO CHANGE VISIBILITY')) {
        //first option:
        $('#the_input').show();

        //second option:
        $('#the_input').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
    } else {
        //first option:
        $('#the_input').hide();

        //second option:
        $('#the_input').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rnDwr/7/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[name="billing_method"]').change(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        $('#the_input').css('visibility', function () {
            return (that.find('option:selected').text() === "CLICK THIS TO CHANGE VISIBILITY") ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        });
    });
});
```

---

References

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)